# vitest and svelte component's onMount

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component, vitest

I'm trying to use Svelte to create a simple reactive component. The component loads data from an api server `onMount` and updates a reactive value (which updates a html element).

I have a simple vitest that renders the component and verifies the value of the html element. However while running under vitest the `onMount` is never called and hence the api call is never made. What am I missing ?

`Component.svelte`:

```
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    export let name = 'world';

    onMount(async () => {
        console.log('chat onMount event!');
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8081/api');
        // for this example, assume name returned by api is FOO
        name = data.name;
    });

</script>

<div id="#element">
    <b> Hello {name}</b>
</div>
```

`index.test.js`:

```
import { expect, test } from 'vitest';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/svelte';
import Component from '../src/lib/Component.svelte';

test('should render', () => {
    render(Component);

    const heading = screen.getByText('Hello FOO');
    expect(heading).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After some sleuthing I stumbled on this issue: https://github.com/vitest-dev/vitest/issues/2834

As I'm running Svelte 4.0.0 the `onMount` is no longer invoked under vitest, hence I had to ad this to `vite.config.js` to make it work:

```
{
      test: {
        alias: [{ find: /^svelte$/, replacement: 'svelte/internal' }],
        ....
       },
       ....
}
```